# How to read an integer from a socket in C

Tags: c, arrays, sockets, char, int

I am trying to read in the char array from the socket and get the integer value which can then be used in a for loop. Sadly I am getting a segmentation fault at atoi(). What am I doing wrong?

```
bytesRead = read(sock, buffer, 1024);
buffer[bytesRead] = '\0';
char tmp[bytesRead];                // I suspect creating this shorter 
strncpy(tmp, buffer, bytesRead);    // array is not necessary... but not sure.
int num = atoi(tmp);
```

Comment: it depends on how it's written on the other side.  By the way, that code wouldn't compile...

Comment: Are you sure the bytes you're reading are ASCII?

Comment: Have you the code of client writing into the socket ?

Comment: Put a break point in your code at the point of error.  View the actual value contained in `tmp` at that point.  You may find that the actual contents do not match what you expected, and you can make adjustments in your code accordingly.

Comment: `atoi()` expects a C-"string". C-"string"s are **`0`-terminated** `char`-arrays. Is `tmp` a C-"string"?

Comment: "*I suspect creating this shorter array is not necessary*" did you try without it?

Comment: @ethang: The other side (for now) is terminal + telnet. The code does compile.

Comment: Austin: Yes

Ôrel: No code yet, just using telnet

ryyker: I'm cross compiling for arm and don't know how to debug this 
way. Maybe that should be my focus... 

alk: I think tmp is a C-"string" but not certain. How would I know/check?

Comment: Why do you try to copy the string from `buffer` to `tmp`? Why not just call `atoi(buffer)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure `tmp` is a C-"string", that is carries the `0` terminator. change the following:

```
char tmp[bytesRead];
```

to be

```
char tmp[bytesRead + 1] = "";
```

The modifications above do two things:

1. Allocate one more bytes then you will use.
2. Set all bytes to zero.

So if you overwrite the 1<sup>st</sup> `bytesRead` bytes by the call to `strncpy()` the last byte stays untouched and with this continues to be `'\0'`, that is it `0`-terminates the `char`-array and with this make it a C-"string".

---

Btw, this line:

```
buffer[bytesRead] = '\0';
```

requires `buffer` to refer to at least `1024 + 1` bytes ...

---

Introducing the usage of `tmp` however isn't necessary. The code also might look like this:

```
char buffer[1024 + 1];
ssize_t result = read(sock, buffer, sizeof buffer - 1);
if (-1 == result) 
{
  perror("read() failed");
}
else
{
  size_t bytesRead = result;
  buffer[bytesRead] = '\0';
  int num = atoi(buffer);
  if (0 == num)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "atoi() (might have) failed");
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: But why copy the string from `buffer` to `tmp` at all, when you can just call `atoi(buffer)`?

Comment: @davmac: Do not ask me, ask the OP ... ;-)

Comment: `requires buffer to refer to at least 1024 + 1 bytes ...` It also requires bytesRead to be non-negative, which cannot be guaranteed ...

Comment: @wildplasser: Absolutly!